# Seed multiple custom rows/entries in ModelFactory Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can I seed multiple rows using ModelFactory in Laravel?

Inside `ModelFactory.php` I have the following code:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    static $password;

    return [
        'name' => 'Admin',
        'Description' => 'Administrators have full access to everything.'
    ];
});
```

How can I add the following arrays, without using raw expressions?

```
[
    'name' => 'Admin',
    'description' => 'Administrators have full access to everything.',
],
[
    'name' => 'User',
    'description' => 'User have normal access.',
],
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use defineAs and state to make different types of users. Like this: `$factory->state(App\User::class, 'admin', function...`

Answer (score 6):

You can use sequence()

```
User::factory()->count(2)->sequence(['name' => 'admin'],['name' => 'user'])
->create()
```

example from laravel documentation

```
$users = User::factory()
            ->count(10)
            ->sequence(fn ($sequence) => ['name' => 'Name '.$sequence->index])
            ->create();
```

source https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#sequences

Comment: Thanks for that, had no idea about sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to add 100 users in your database.

Create a `UserFactory.php` in `database/factories`:

```php
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    return [
        'name' => 'Admin',
        'Description' => 'Administrators have full access to everything.'
    ];
});
```

Then, in `database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php`:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\User::class, 100)->create();
    }
}
```

You can find more details [about seeding in the Laravel official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/seeding#using-model-factories).

Comment: But this doesn't allow you to seed custom data, you are having 100 entries of fake data.

Comment: If you want custom data, you will have to write them all "manually".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have one or two columns to have custom data, you can use `each` function after creating entries.

```
$names = ['admin', 'user', 'author', 'subscriber'];

factory(App\User::class, 100)->create()->each(function () use ($names) {
     $user->name = $names[array_rand($names)];
     $user->save();
});
```

*Note: Use your own logic inside each function to feed the custom data.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way than Raghavendra's proposal (creates one entry per name):

```
$names = ['admin', 'user', 'author', 'subscriber'];

collect($names)->each(function($name) {
    App\Models\User::factory()->create($name);
});
```